# Synchronize GAC across multiple systems

Tags: .net, deployment, gac

I'm looking for a tool that keep GAC synchronized across different systems. when a new assembly added to one system, it should be GACed on other systems automatically.

Thanks

Comment: You might get better answers at serverfault.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are deploying to a farm; IMO, the best way to do this is not via the GAC, but simply by including the required dlls in the project(s) you need. All of them. Disk space is cheap, and the convenience of being able to use "robocopy" (or similar) to distribute to the farm is very attractive.

There are very few times when the GAC is truly *required* - some of the "serviced component" scenarios, for example. For most others probing paths are fine.

Comment: Thanks for you reply,
actually, I've a services component scenario, where the server application looks GAC for assemblies.